# breqn and lineno incompatibility

Tags: line-numbering, breqn

Journals often require line numbering for the review process. This is achieved using `lineno` package. Next, it seems like a good idea to use `breqn` package (`dmath` environment) to auto-break long formulas.

But, not switching line numbering off before `dmath` environment (`\begin{nolinenumbers}`, `\end{nolinenumbers}`), causes `pdftex` to hang (it just consumes 100% CPU, and compilation never finishes).

1. Why is this happening?
2. How to redefine `dmath` (and `dmath*`) environment to have `nolinenumbers` environment automaticly added around it.

   ```
   \documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{breqn}
   \usepackage{lineno}

   \begin{document}
   \linenumbers

   First paragraph.

   \begin{nolinenumbers}
   \begin{dmath}
   f(x)=x^9+x^8-x^7+x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1.
   \end{dmath}
   \end{nolinenumbers}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: Do you really mean `pdftex`? Your MWE compiles fine on my machine using `pdfLaTeX`. For your other request you can use `etoolbox` and issue `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{dmath}{\begin{nolinenumbers}} \AfterEndEnvironment{dmath}{\end{nolinenumbers}}`

Comment: I didn't say that this code didn't compile. If you read carefully you will see "But, not switching line numbering off before dmath environment...causes pdftex to hang". For this code to compile, I have to use `\begin{nolinenumbers}` ... `\end{nolinenumbers}`.  Your solu

Comment: Your solution for the 2nd question doesn't seem to work: `./Untitled.tex:21: LaTeX Error: \begin{nolinenumbers} on input line 17 ended by
 \end{document}.`

Comment: How can you use `pdftex` and `\documentclass`? Anyway, the lineno manual states that it does not work well with math environments and provides a few patches for this. As you identified, one way to solve is to turn off line numbering for math.

Comment: After clicking _Typeset_ in _TeXShop_, I see process `pdftex` consuming 99% CPU.

Comment: The latest release of breqn inserts `\nolinenumbers` automatically. (best I could do with little time...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `etoolbox` before `breqn`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lineno}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{dmath}{\begin{nolinenumbers}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{dmath}{\end{nolinenumbers}}


\begin{document}
\linenumbers

First paragraph.

%\begin{nolinenumbers}
\begin{dmath}
f(x)=x^9+x^8-x^7+x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1.
\end{dmath}
%\end{nolinenumbers}

Second Paragraph
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what my comment suggested, the order of loading `etoolbox` is important.

Answer (score 5):

The `lineno` manual states that it "does not work well with display math" (p.13). One way is to wrap equations in in the `linenomath` environment for common math environments, but this does not work for `dmath`. So we may use `etoolbox` to patch `dmath` to exclude linenumbers automatically (and equivalently for `dmath*`).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{lineno}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{dmath}{\begin{nolinenumbers}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{dmath}{\end{nolinenumbers}}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{dmath*}{\begin{nolinenumbers}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{dmath*}{\end{nolinenumbers}}


\begin{document}
\linenumbers

First paragraph.

\begin{dmath}
f(x)=x^9+x^8-x^7+x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1.
\end{dmath}

Second paragraph

\begin{dmath*}
f(x)=x^9+x^8-x^7+x^6-x^5-x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1.
\end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Loading `etoolbox` after `breqn` and carefully reading the error message reveals that `etoolbox` fails to patch `\end` and hence the `\AfterEndEnvironment` will not work. There appears to be an incompatibility (probably `breqn` patches something as well). So simply load  `etoolbox` before.

Comment: `linenomath` doesn't work with `dmath` environment! If it did, I would not be asking this question!